How to run pegasosQSVC in backend using qiskit ibm runtime session?
I am trying to run pegasosQSVC on quantum backend using a qiskit-ibm-runtime session, following is the code I am using :
from qiskit_ibm_runtime import Session, Sampler 
from qiskit_machine_learning.algorithms import PegasosQSVC 
from qiskit_machine_learning.kernels import FidelityQuantumKernel 


with Session(service= service, backend=backend) as session:
    sampler = Sampler(backend=backend, session=session) 
    fidelity = ComputeUncompute(sampler=sampler)
    
    # setting the kernel

    qkernel = FidelityQuantumKernel(feature_map=transpiled_featuremap, fidelity=fidelity) 

    # fitting the algorithm 
    
    pegasos = PegasosQSVC(quantum_kernel=qkernel, C = C, num_steps=tau)

    pegasos.fit(train_features,train_labels)

    pegasos_score = pegasos.score(test_features,test_labels)

print(f"Pegasosqsvc classification test score: {pegasos_score*100}") 

The ComputeUncompute method here is modified. I initially had a problem with it, which gave an error that the circuits do not follow the ISA of the backend, but I solved it by using a modified local copy of the method to transpile the circuits it uses in state fidelity calculation. Now, the problem I have is that the code runs fine, and when I check in the IBM platform, it shows that the job reached the backend. However, in my notebook, the cell doesn't stop running, and I don't get any score back from pegasos_score.
NOTE: the code works just fine when I run it locally, and it gives normal results.
Is there any problem with the way I wrote the code? How can I retrieve my desired result?
